# Is there any way to change bottomsheet direction left or right

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

Bottomsheet gravity from bottom to any other side like left or right.

Answer (score 1):

SlidingPaneLayout is perfect for sliding from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as the name suggests, it slides from the bottom only.

There's plenty of 3rd party libraries for dialogs with different pop directions, here is one: https://github.com/orhanobut/dialogplus

Comment: I checked it, doesn't provide Horizontal directions.

Comment: For left to right you can use the native navigation drawer